# No usable version of libssl was found after inserting PAT in Azure self-hosted

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

After clean install of Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS, I try to run the ./config.sh it fails after inserting the personal access token with this error

```
No usable version of libssl was found
./config.sh: line 86: 23573 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./bin/Agent.Listener configure "$@"
```

How do I fix this? I already tried installing libssl but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fix this? I already tried installing libssl but it doesn't work.

*The reason could be because of version issues with Open SSL libraries and .Net core*

*As mentioned in this [document](https://dev.to/n3wt0n/no-usable-version-of-the-libssl-was-found-solved-2ffa) there are 2 ways to fix the issues*

1. *Upgrading your .Net core version to latest will fix the issues*

[image]

2. *If you can't upgrade your .Net core version then install the older version*

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the answer is to go back to 20.04 LTS since the Azure DevOps agent is based on .NET Core 3.1 which is only compatible with OpenSSL 1.x whereas Ubuntu 22.04 only supports OpenSSL 3.0. I tried a variety of tricks to get OpenSSL 1.1 installed but that then broke the SSL connection to Azure DevOps.